# Use Case Class To Trim DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql, azure-cosmosdb, case-class, databricks

I have the following code. In cosmo giant JSONs containing data are stored. Currently, the display command displays all of the fields in the Azure Cosmos DB location. However, I only want to display the fields specified in the Employee Class; smtNr, smtDt, prcCnyCd, and busLinCd. Can anyone explain why this code isn't working or how to do this using case Classes?

```
val sourceConfigMap = Map(
  "Endpoint" -> "https://endpoint/",
  "Masterkey" -> "masterkey",
  "Database" -> "database",
  "Collection" -> "collection",
  "ConnectionMode" -> "DirectHttps",
)

final case class Employee(smtNr: String, smtDt: String, prcCnyCd: String, busLinCd: String)

val config = Config(sourceConfigMap)
val output = spark.sqlContext.read.cosmosDB(config).as[Employee]

display(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a schema out of the Case Class Object and then read using the schema method applying the created schema.

```
val config = Config(sourceConfigMap)
val schema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[Employee].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
val output = spark.sqlContext.read.schema(schema).cosmosDB(config)
```